# Wamp 2.2 install PEAR

Tags: php, windows-7, wamp, pear

My operating system is Windows 7.
I got my WAMP2.2 install in my computer.
Then I try to install `PEAR`.
However, I can not find my `go-pear.bat` file in my wamp directory.
Fine. I download in here:  `http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`
and install using this file.
I put the file in

```
 C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/pear/go-pear.phar
```

Run the command: `php -d phar.require_hash=0 PEAR/go-pear.phar`
After the installation, I include the path of pear in `php.ini` in php and apache folder.
I also include `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/` in windows `$PATH` variable.
But when I run pear command. It said it can not find the pear command.
I check the folder and just find a file called `pear.bat` and `pear.ini`.
I tried to run `pear.bat` again in command line. It still does not work.
Experts, please help on this issue.

Comment: just a guess. try restarting your system.

Comment: As far as I remember (it's been some time since I did it last time), you need to go through pear.bat and check/correct paths to php.exe

Comment: you can refer this link for full installation [installing pear in wamp server](http://mynewtec.blogspot.in/2011/11/install-pear-in-wamp-server-22-with-php.html)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Ok since many people may be asking the same thing. Let's suppose the following. 
I'm currently running 2.2 E which includes Apache 2.2.22 – Mysql 5.5.24 – PHP 5.3.13 XDebug 2.1.2 XDC 1.5 PhpMyadmin 3.4.10.1 SQLBuddy 1.3.3 webGrind 1.0

Now, to install PEAR do the following:

Download this file:
http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

And put it on your WAMP server directory under the PHP version on the bin folder. 
Run the command to install PEAR and you're over it.

**Example** (defaults, no change has been done)

1. Get the file on the link ->http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
2. Go to this directory C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
3. Open command prompt (cmd.exe). Supposing you're using Windows Vista and higher, press Start, type "cmd.exe" and right click on it and select run as administrator/CTRL+SHIFT+Enter (Haven't tested on non-priviliges rights)
4. Use Window's cd command to change the directory to the *go-pear.phar* file you've just downloaded. In my case I'll be pin pointing it to my own directory, so I did it like follows:

   `cd "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13"`
5. Press Enter. You should note that instead of saying "C:\system\32" is now displaying C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13
6. Write the following command and press Enter:

   `php -d phar.require_hash=0 go-pear.phar`
7. Select whether you like or not a local copy or a system one. By typing `system:local` and pressing enter you'll install a local copy. By typing `system` and pressing enter you'll install a system-wide copy.
8. Type `yes` to confirm the option chosen.
9. The next list of directories, will be the referring directories that PEAR will install its components. If you select from 1 - 12 you can change the directory you'd like to install. By typing `all` and pressing Enter you'll be able to change them all in a queued manner. *In my case, I just pressed Enter and left all defaults*

**DO THE FOLLOWING IN CASE YOU CONTINUE TO HAVE SOME LISTINGS**
 11. It is very probable that afterwards you'll receive a message like:

> WARNING! The include+path defined in the currently used php.ini does not contain the PEAR PHP directory you just specified:  If the specified directory is also not in the include_path used by your scripts, you will have problems getting any PEAR packages working.

Below it will also appear:

> Would you like to alter php.ini ? [Y/n]:

Type `y` and press enter

This should put you running with PEAR on WAMP server :)

Comment: Seriously - I don't know why this doesn't have 10,000+ up-votes.  Thanks SO much.

Comment: work like heaven with no trouble! - Windows 7 & WAMP 2.4

Comment: Does the job for me, win7. Needed to right-click cmd and "Run as administrator", otherwise I got a "permission denied".

Comment: I wish all answer were like this. Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: The go-pear.phar proposed is not good and this error is coming : manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB in phar

Comment: This method is still working very well on Windows 10 + WAMP 3.1.3 x64. Thanks. I recommend also running the generated PEAR_ENV.reg file after the process ends.

Answer (score 0):

`pear.bat` is the executable on windows. You have to put that directory in your system's `PATH` variable for the command to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

All the steps mentioned to below link for GUI based - easy understanding review and setup:

[Click here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/29976/install-pear-on-windows-7-64x-using-wamp/)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a more current answer. On Windows 10 I had to edit .bash_profile to add the following:

```
function __pear {
    pear.bat $@
}

alias pear=__pear
```