# Enable phar extension in old php installation in windows 10

Tags: php, phar

```
$ php composer.phar install
PHP's phar extension is missing. Composer requires it to run. Enable the extension or recompile php without --disable-phar then try again.
```

I trying the extension html2wiki (Unsupported) of mediawiki, where I need to install the composer to make it work.

My php version is: 7.0.13 and my question is

How to enable this extension https://pecl.php.net/package/phar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install / enable the PHP phar extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047487/how-do-i-install-enable-the-php-phar-extension)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am using windows.

Comment: You are using wamp ? `php -d phar.require_hash=0 go-pear.phar` and restart wamp.
if it's not working please follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13032983/5391965

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12800017/5391965, download a new composer.phar et put it in C:\composer\composer.phar

Comment: You are using
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881924/change-php-version-used-by-composer-on-windows

Comment: There are perhaps four parts to make html2wiki which I am not really successful yet.
1) PHP (old version) 1a) If Phar extension is missing then I may need a way to make extension work 2) Composer that is compitable with html2wiki 3) Start of the mediawiki without any exceptions 4) Daunting task to converting 1000+ pages of documents to wiki

Comment: I will start with wamp and see how things go